# error while uploading data on hdfs from local file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

Hi I have just started working on Hadoop. When I am trying to upload data on HDFS to run a mapreduce job on hadoop. I am encountering problems. I run the below command

```
hduser@bharti-desktop:/home/maitreyee/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg
```

and following error pops up in the terminal:

```
14/12/04 16:59:48 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/12/04 16:59:48 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/12/04 16:59:48 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/12/04 16:59:48 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/12/04 16:59:48 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/12/04 16:59:48 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/12/04 16:59:49 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/12/04 16:59:49 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/12/04 16:59:49 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
```

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS and hadoop 1.2.1. Kindly suggest any possible solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just a warning. So if everything else works fine, you shouldn't worry to much.

Comment: If you set the `hadoop/bin` in `PATH` you don't need to switch to hadoop installation folder for running `hadoop` commands..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not provide the whole error popup of terminal so,

Looks like you might have some XML formatting errors in your hdfs-site.xml or mapred-site.xml or core-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.

Every time I want to do something with on HDFS with bin/hdfs dfs command, I got this warning. But I was still able to upload, list, view, and remove directories and files in HDFS.

After a 2-hour continuously error shooting on core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, and slaves ... I checked the spelling of every word and even the file encoding since hdfs.xml claiming to use UTF-8 but actually use ANSI, I finally found... It's just because I forgot to put a set of

```
<property> </property>
```

around

```
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>Jing6.zhu</value>
```

in yarn-site.xml...

**I suggest people with this problem rename each xml file of a time to disable the custom settings, for testing which file caused the problem.**

By the way, I also found I misplaced some setting on log-aggregation in mapred-site.xml instead of in yarn-site.xml, but it didn't cause any warning or error message at all.